# sbt hangs during tests on travis-ci

Tags: scala, sbt, travis-ci

I have an open source scala project (https://github.com/lucidsoftware/xtract). The build on travis-ci consistently hangs while running tests, for both scala 2.11 and 2.12. Sometimes it hangs after compiling and before any output from tests, other times it hangs in the middle of running tests. I have tried several iterations of changing the travis, inclding trying with and without `sudo: false`, different versions of sbt, splitting up the sbt commands in different ways, using both oraclejdk8 and openjdk8, etc.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Sample failure: https://travis-ci.org/lucidsoftware/xtract/jobs/280974227

My .travis.yml:

```
language: scala

scala:
  - 2.11.11
  - 2.12.3

jdk:
  - openjdk8

dist: trusty
sudo: false

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
    - $HOME/.sbt/

after_success:
  - sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION package
  - |
    if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ] || ([ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == false ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == master ])
    then
      mkdir ~/.pgp
      echo $PGP_PUBLIC | base64 --decode > ~/.pgp/pubring
      echo $PGP_SECRET | base64 --decode > ~/.pgp/secring
      echo "Publishing snapshot"
      sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION xtract/publishSigned xtractTesting/publishSigned
    fi
deploy:
  api_key: $GITHUB_AUTH
  file:
    - xtract-core/target/**/*.jar
    - testing/target/**/*.jar
  file_glob: true
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true

install: sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION update
before_cache:
  #Avoid unncessary cache updates
  - find $HOME/.ivy2 -name "ivydata-*.properties" -print -delete
  - find $HOME/.sbt  -name "*.lock" -print -delete
```

**EDIT**

Failure with `-debug` option on sbt: https://travis-ci.org/lucidsoftware/xtract/jobs/281081862

The last thing it does is

```
[debug] Running TaskDef(com.lucidchart.open.xtract.DefaultXmlReadersSpec, specs2 Specification fingerprint, false, [SuiteSelector])
```

**Edit 2**

Some notes. This project has multiple subprojects. The build pauses while running tests, and the test are in their own project, because they depend on both the core code, and an a separate sub-project for specs2 matchers specific to the project.

Comment: lots of people (including me) use Travis to run sbt tests all the time no problem, so presumably the problem must involve something specific to your project. running `sbt --debug` instead of plain `sbt` might help track down the hang. you might also see if Travis provides any way to obtain a JVM stack trace when a job hangs, to help troubleshoot

Comment: Have you tried with [forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html) enabled?

Comment: @SzymonBiliński I have tried forking. I got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally figured out  what was going on.

I was able to reproduce the problem in the travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502276-986baf0 docker container. Although to get sbt running I had to find and install the sbt-launch.jar for version 1.1.1 because the installed bootstrapper doesn't work for any version 1.0 or higher. I deleted several folders from the home folder with stuff for other languages to free disk space for downloading artifacts.

After it stalled I took a thread dump of the java process (by sending it a QUIT signal).

The output included this:

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"specs2-6":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fc6a4b9fb68 (object 0x00000000997e39f0, a sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathFilter),
  which is held by "specs2-3"
"specs2-3":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fc6d0df7298 (object 0x0000000098f700b0, a sbt.internal.inc.classpath.ClasspathUtilities$$anon$1),
  which is held by "specs2-6"
```

So I knew there was a deadlock which was preventing it from progressing.

After some googling I found a bug for mockito (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1067).

A workaround is to disable parallelExecution for tests.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 10min compiler timeout. Maybe the memory limits cause too much swapping.

`-Xms2048M
-Xmx2048M
-Xss6M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Add to your `build.sbt`

```
logLevel := Level.Debug
```

so that you can use the log-debug to check what is going in on. In my case sbt was looking for

```
sbt-chain: module revision found in cache: com.fasterxml.jackson#jackson-parent;2.8
[debug]         tried /home/travis/.ivy2/local/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jars/jackson-bom.jar
[debug]         tried https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jackson-bom-2.8.11.jar
[debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jackson-bom-2.8.11.jar
[debug]         tried /home/travis/.sbt/preloaded/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jars/jackson-bom.jar
[debug]         tried file:////home/travis/.sbt/preloaded/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jackson-bom-2.8.11.jar
[debug]         tried https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jackson-bom-2.8.11.jar
[debug] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.11/jackson-bom-2.8.11.jar
```

Comment: I've tried with debugging enabled, the last line is just sbt saying it is running a TaskDef for the DefaultXmlReadersSpec (see my first edit).

Comment: have you tried to add `travis_wait 30` to as prefix to your sbt command?. That is `install: travis_wait 30 sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION update`